# Why i am getting this IOException from Below Code?

Tags: android, file, exception, bitmap

i have my `bitmap` and `I want to convert my bitmap to save as image in another new file by below code.`

**Note:** Its Working fine in all devices Except Galaxy S3. can any one help me to make this code workable in S3. i always getting this Toast while converting to new file. anyone have idea what the problem might occurring.

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                selectedImagePath = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg";

                Log.i("TAG", "new selectedImagePath before file "
                        + selectedImagePath);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        selectedImagePath);

                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, fos);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Sorry, Camera Crashed-Please Report as Crash A.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the value of e.getMessage()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible the storage is not in a state to be written to, there are a number of reason this could happen. You should be checking [`getExternalStorageState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) prior to accessing the external storage. Even if it is not happening on other devices, it *could* happen, so best to guard against it.

If external storage is `MEDIA_MOUNTED`, and your problem still persists, you can get a better handle on what is happening by looking at what caused your exception by adding `e.getMessage()` to your `Toast` or logs.

You also appear to be using the top-level directory for storing your files.  This should not cause a technical problem, but is considered best to create a subdirectory for your app and store files there.  From the [`getExternalStorageDirectory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) docs --

> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in
>   order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace.